# How to lock a directory for exclusive access in PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, locking, flock

I'm using the [flock()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) method to get an advisory lock on a directory, and prevent another process from accessing the same directory at the same time. Because `flock()` operates on a file handle, I have to open a handle on the directory first:

```php
fopen('.', 'r');
```

However, this does not work on Windows:

> fopen(.): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Is there a way to do the same on Windows, or is it a limitation of this platform?

Answer (score 0):

*Don't think you can in Windows without a file system driver.*

**But try to use a file as a reference.** Create a file in the folder called `.locker` and lock/unlock it. If it's locked, means folder should not be touched... otherwise.

**Or... use a database to store concurrently accessible data.** File disk operations are much slower. This can become a bottleneck for your site's performance.